# Get text from UITextView Swift 2

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

I m doing an iOS project using swift 2, I have a UITableView with custom cells. I have one cell with a UITextView and a simple label, and I wan't to get the value of this UITextView when it's modified, but it's not like UITextFields, I can't use on edit begin method. How can I do that ?

Here is my code to define my custom cell :

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CurrentFormTableView.CellIdentifiers.ParagraphCell, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ParagraphCell
                cell.display(block)
                cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
                tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
                tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 160.0
                return cell
```

And here is my ParagraphCell.swift

```
import UIKit

protocol ParagraphCell {
    func update ParagraphCell(cell: ParagraphCell, rep: String)
}

class ParagraphCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerField: UITextView!


    var delegate: ParagraphCell Delegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        let borderColor : UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.85, green: 0.85, blue: 0.85, alpha: 1.0)
        answerField.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        answerField.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor
        answerField.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0

    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func display(block: Block){
        titleLabel.text = block.title
        answerField.text = ""
    }

//THIS METHOD IS NEVER CALLED... 
    func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) { //Handle the text changes here
        print(textView.text); //the textView parameter is the textView where text was changed
        delegate?.update ParagraphCell(self, rep: textView.text)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `answerField.delegate = self` in awakeFromNib to receive delegate callbacks.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    let borderColor : UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.85, green: 0.85, blue: 0.85, alpha: 1.0)
    answerField.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    answerField.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor
    answerField.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    answerField.delegate = self // create delegate reference
}
```

You'll also need to add `UITextViewDelegate` to your class protocol declaration:

```
class ParagraphCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate { }
```

Comment: If I do that I have this error : cannot assign value of type ParagraphCell to type UITextViewDelegate?

Comment: You need to add UITextViewDelegate to the ParagraphCell protocol declaration

Comment: `class ParagraphCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {`

Comment: Ohhhh Waww, I never saw this notation before ! it solved the problem thanks a lot my friend ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to set the delegate of the UITextView to the object where you want to put your textViewDidChange method. At the moment you have it in the ParagraphCell class, but it would probably make more sense to put this into your view controller instead, and make the view controller the delegate.

Answer (score 1):

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CurrentFormTableView.CellIdentifiers.ParagraphCell, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ParagraphCell
                cell.display(block)
                cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
                cell.answerField.delegate =  self
                tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
                tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 160.0
                return cell
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use `didEndEditing` delegate method which is getting called after editing will complete.

You can set tag to textview as `indexpath.row` means row number to differentiate the textview in delegate method.

Or you can implement delegate method in custom tableviewcell class.

Better way is to implement delegate method in `viewcontroller` and set tag to `textview` in `cellforrowatindexpath`.

hope this will help :)

Comment: `textViewDidEndEditing` getting called when you finish editing of textview. like if you click on other controls or you switch to other controls from textview or you resign keyboard etc